# Open a folder in bash, when the foldername contains a blank space

Tags: linux, terminal

I am new to Ubuntu and I have recently learned how to open a folder in the terminal for example

```
cd Desktop
```

A problem occurred when I tried to open a folder called "ovn 1.2.1". When running

```
cd ovn 1.2.1
```

in the terminal, the terminal answers with "could not find any folder called ovn".

Answer (score 2):

If by map you mean directory such as `Desktop`, on your terminal, escape the spaces, like this:

```
$ cd ovn\ 1.2.1
```

Or, enclose in quotes, `'` or `"` quotes are fine:

```
$ cd 'ovn 1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use quotes (`"`s) to shield the directory name from the shell:

```
mureinik@computer ~ $ mkdir "ovn 1.2.1"
mureinik@computer ~ $ cd "ovn 1.2.1"
mureinik@computer ~/ovn 1.2.1 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`cd ovn\ 1.2.1`

you can also start typing `cd ovn` and then hit `Tab` key for autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Try `ovn\ 1.2...`

`\`  is treated as space in terminal.